Convert continuous system of equations into difference system
I have a differential system of equations like below:
\begin{equation*}
  \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
      & \dot{X} (t) = A_1X(t) + B_1U(t) \\
      & \dot{Y} (t) = A_2Y(t) + B_2U(t)+CX(t)
    \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{equation*}
I need to get a difference system of equations from it, like this:
\begin{equation*}
  \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
      & X(t_{k+1}) = k_{11} X(t_{k}) + k_{12} U(t_k) \\
      & Y(t_{k+1}) = k_{21} Y(t_{k}) + k_{22} X(t_{k})+ k_{23} U(t_k)
    \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{equation*}
I obtained the first dependence using the analytical method (with an assumption that U~const on $(t_{k}, t_{k+1})$, but I have very little idea how to obtain the second (don't know to deal with X(t) there). Any help and ideas are welcome!
Edit:
I think i understood the idea, so when i analytically solve the second equation i need to just use the first one:
\begin{equation}
Y(t_{k+1})= Y(t_{k})e^{At} +e^{At}\int_{t_k}^{t_(k+1)} e^{-A\tau}X(\tau)d\tau + ... = \\Y(t_{k})e^{At} +e^{At}\int_{t_k}^{t_(k+1)} e^{-A\tau}(k_{11}(\tau)X(\theta) + k_{12}(\tau) U(\theta))d\tau  + ...
\end{equation}
where $t_{k} < \theta < t_{k+1}$
I still need a bit to realise it, but i guesse it worked...

So you want to discretize the continuous time ODE using zero order hold for the input $U(t)$?

@Kwin van der Veen
If i understood correctly, then yes. I want to discretize with a constant step and get the dependence on 1 previous value.
A huge problem for me (maybe i don't understand something) is how to do it for Y. For x it is quite simple, because it depends only on the inputs U, while y depends not only on the inputs, but also on X(u) or the previous values of x.

Combining the system of ordinary differential equation into on system allows one to use some linear algebra properties in order to discretize your system. The combining into one system yields
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{X}(t) \\ \dot{Y}(t)
\end{bmatrix} = 
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
A_1 & 0 \\ C & A_2
\end{bmatrix}}_\bar{A}
\begin{bmatrix}
X(t) \\ Y(t)
\end{bmatrix} + 
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
B_1 \\ B_2
\end{bmatrix}}_\bar{B} U(t).
$$
Discretizing this system using zero order hold with time step size $T$ can be obtained using
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\bar{A}_d & \bar{B}_d \\ 0 & I
\end{bmatrix} = e^{\begin{bmatrix}
\bar{A} & \bar{B} \\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} T},
$$
with the above equation using the matrix exponential, such that the discrete time system can be written as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
X(t+T) \\ Y(t+T)
\end{bmatrix} = 
\bar{A}_d
\begin{bmatrix}
X(t) \\ Y(t)
\end{bmatrix} + 
\bar{B}_d\,U(t).
$$

Thanks for providing the literature links. It has become much clearer, I will try to figure it out and compare it with my previous solution.
